# Is there a built in way to declare on a class that it should be available for dependency injection?

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection

In a .NET app we have lots of classes that rely on dependency injection:

```cs
public class MyClass {
    public MyClass(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory) ...
```

The best practice here appears to be that anything using the DI pattern should be part of the DI services too.

So, rather than calling `GetService<ILoggerFactory>` in the class we'd use `[FromServices]`, and to register it we need to add it to `Program.cs` or `Startup.cs`:

```cs
builder.Services.AddTransient<MyClass>();
```

Which is fine for a few, but we now have a *lot* of these and it feels like technical debt to hand-maintain a long list of classes.

```cs
builder.Services
    .AddTransient<MyClass>()
    .AddTransient<MyClass2>()
    .AddTransient<MyClass3>()
    ...
    .AddTransient<MyClass150>();
```

I have a workaround, which looks like this:

```cs
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
public sealed class RegisterServiceAttribute : Attribute
{
    public ServiceLifetime Lifetime { get; }
    public Type? ServiceType { get; }

    public RegisterServiceAttribute(ServiceLifetime lifetime, Type? serviceType) => 
        (Lifetime, ServiceType) = (lifetime, serviceType);

    public RegisterServiceAttribute(ServiceLifetime lifetime) => 
        (Lifetime) = (lifetime);
}
```

```cs
namespace Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

public static class RegisterServiceAttributeExtensions
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddServicesWithAttribute(this IServiceCollection services, Assembly assembly)
    {
        var typesRegisteredByAttribute =
            from t in assembly.GetTypes().AsParallel()
            where !t.IsAbstract
            let attributes = t.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(RegisterServiceAttribute), true)
            where attributes?.Length > 0
            select new { ImplementationType = t, Attribute = attributes.Cast<RegisterServiceAttribute>().First() };

        foreach (var regAttr in typesRegisteredByAttribute.ToArray())
            services.Add(new(
                regAttr.Attribute.ServiceType ?? regAttr.ImplementationType,
                regAttr.ImplementationType,
                regAttr.Attribute.Lifetime));

        return services;
    }
}
```

And these let us declare *in the class* that it should be in the DI services:

```cs
[RegisterService(ServiceLifetime.Transient)]
public class MyClass {
```

Then in `Program.cs`:

```cs
services.AddServicesWithAttribute(...get whatever assembly I expect them in);
```

However, all this reflection slows my application's start up, as it now needs to reflect all the types to find the 150 or so that use or inherit `[RegisterService]`, is there a better way to flag those classes in their definition?

Implementations are messy too - they can be added:

```cs
[RegisterService(ServiceLifetime.Transient, typeof(IMyInterface))]
public class MyClass : IMyInterface {
```

So I can use `[FromServices] IMyInterface myInterface`, but if `MyClass` *doesn't* implement `IMyInterface` I have some nasty run time startup crashes. Ideally the compiler would know that.

This also feels like I must be reinventing the wheel - surely there is already something that does this in .NET's DI model?

If there isn't is there some good reason that they haven't implemented it that I missed?

Comment: I'm not a DI expert but I know that you can write logic specific to automate DI if you're using Autofac, for instance. Would you consider using something other than the Microsoft built-in IOC container?

Comment: Have a look at [Using Scrutor to automatically register your services with the ASP.NET Core DI container](https://andrewlock.net/using-scrutor-to-automatically-register-your-services-with-the-asp-net-core-di-container)

Comment: from that link you could make up a decent answer, some sample code, that link for extra information... @pfx

Comment: @pfx cheers and that's certainly an nice implementation of a similar idea, but it has the same problems (reflection hit on start up) and still has the logic of whether a class is a DI service in the start up rather than the class. I'll definitely check it out.

Comment: @zoharpeled I'd consider it, but does that help here? I get a different service collection with some extra features, but I still need to register all my classes as services.

Comment: Check this: https://github.com/giggio/sourceinject

Comment: Or this: https://jasperfx.github.io/lamar/guide/

Comment: @artur oh I like that `SourceInject` - same idea, but code generation instead of reflection. It has the the potential to fix the interface/implementation too. However, this _still_ feels like reinventing the wheel somewhat - surely every app large enough to use DI for it's own DI-dependant  classes (which is supposed to be the best practice) needs a solution like this?

Comment: If I were to choose, I'd take Lamar because it's a successor of the well-known StructureMap but rebuilt ground up for better performance. It also complies with MS rules for DI (which can't be said about many other containers). But, for the best practices, I'd use the old fashion manual registration. No surprises, easy to debug, and easy to inject mocks in [integration tests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-7.0#inject-mock-services). Just use extension methods to register dependencies instead of creating a single big and ugly method.

Comment: Also, using attributes all over the code base is a leaky abstraction. Now, you have to reference the DI library everywhere and create a strong coupling to the chosen container.

Comment: As I wrote, Autofac lets you automate Di, check their documentation for examples.

Comment: @Artur thanks, there's quite a lot in comments - two possible solutions and some reasons not to do it. Could you put all that as an answer? There's more nuance there than fits into comments.

Comment: @ZoharPeled am I missing something? AutoFac replaces `builder.Services.AddTransient<MyClass, IMyInterface>()` with `builder.Register<MyClass>().As<IMyInterface>()`. It does have `builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(MyClass).Assembly)`, which has the same reflection pitfalls and seems to need a lot of conventions (register everything with name like something, rather than opt in to being a service) but it could apply the same solution. There's more detail here than fits in a comment, could you expand to an answer?

Comment: What kind of startup requirements do you have that the loss in startup time is a problem? I've built small and big applications that use Auto-Registration (register types using reflection) and for most applications the loss in startup time is neglectable. What kind of application are you building and why must it start this fast? And have you tested in release mode (without the debugger) what the difference is in startup time?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have enough experience with Autofac to confidently write an answer, or really elaborate on that too much. I did have one project at work that used Autofac for DI, where my team leader wrote some code to automate registration of types based on type names etc'. I'm sorry I can't help more.

Comment: @Steven it's not a particular requirement, just the usual web issue of the first request after a lull or as a new app spins up will be slower for users, and I'd rather not add new bottlenecks if there is a better way.

Comment: Please keep in mind that Auto-Registration using reflection is a *very* common practice, especially for web applications. The only way to speed up that process is to practice Explicit Register, which basically means calling `AddTransient` hundreds of times in code. Or switch to Pure DI. When startup time is a problem, you could consider keeping the web application alive instead of recycling it (configurable in IIS), use a load balancer to ensure traffic is routed to a started application and there are a myriad of other options available.